# Is there a built in function in String.h that returns a substring?

Tags: java, c, string, substring

Say my string is `s="Computer"`. If I were coding in Java, then `C=s.substring(1,3)` would return `C="oup";`.

Is there a built in class function in C which precisely does this? Please do not use pointers.

Comment: It would not return `oup`.

Comment: Strings without pointers is practically an oxymoron in C.

Comment: Use `strncpy(c, s + 1, 3);`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan but that function will return a pointer and OP doesn't want to use pointers! (sarcasm)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza hmm.. I see.

Comment: "built in class function" - Don't try and do C like Java. It's just not going to work. Learn it like a new language, then you might get somewhere.

Comment: Because actually C doesn't have classes at all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any way of doing it without using pointers. Using pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char *s="Computer";
    char sub[20];
    strncpy(sub, s+1, 3);
    printf("%s\n%s", s, sub);
}
```

Comment: That's just sample code. Ideally, if we were to write a substring function code, it should alloc `length` bytes to sub.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
char dest[N];
snprintf(dest, sizeof dest, "%.*s", len, src+start);
```

Note that if you just want to print the result, you don't need space to store the resulting string. Just do:

```
printf("%.*s", len, src+start);
```